# Keras Conv2D input Shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am using Keras for my CNN Model. In that model, I am training it using images. My images are in shape 256*256. However I trained it as 64*64. When I resize my images as 64*64 and trained again my accuracy rate was decreased drastically. What am I missing ?

When I arrange Convolution2D input shape as

```
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,input_shape = (256,256), activation ='relu'))
```

It takes many time. Because of that I arranged my Convolution2D as `classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,input_shape = (64,64), activation ='relu'))` and I trained my first model. It predicting very well.

When I resized my input images shape as 64*64 and training with Convolution2D as

```
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,input_shape = (64,64)
```

my accuracy rate was decreased. What is the problem ?

Here is the code

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,input_shape = (64,64,3), activation ='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=8000,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=800)
```

Here is the my reshape code

```
from PIL import Image
import os
path = 'TestForTrain2'
for file in os.listdir('TestForTrain2'):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join('TestForTrain2', file))
    width, height = img.size
    stringName = str(file)
    print(width," === ",height)
    print(stringName)
    f, e = os.path.splitext(path + file)
    imResize = img.resize((64, 64), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    imResize.save( stringName + '.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

Comment: Please show how do you resize your images? And what do you use to open them? opencv, pillow? In the case, it's opencv don't forget it uses a BGR color format, not RGB one.

Comment: I am confused. What is the difference between your 2 training processes?

Comment: The differences is only the shape of input images. In my first model, input images shape are 256*256. And this model works very well. In my second model I reshape input images as 64*64 and accuracy rate of model is very low. I do not understand the why does it happen.

Comment: @constt I added the reshape code. And also ı have one more question what happens when ı trained 256*256 shapes input images as 64*64 input shapes ? Does it affect the training  or Will CNN make some arragements ?

Comment: @GhostDede, what's the target variable you're trying to predict? From the sequential model definition you've posted, it's not quite clear what is the problem you solve. Do you learn image embeddings or something? I think it would be helpful if you'll post the whole code here.

Answer (score 1):

Your model definition does not seem complete, it seems to miss at least a final `Dense()` layer to perform the actual classification. However, decreasing the input resolution by 4 in 2 dimensions will decrease your 'raw information' input by 16 (4ˆ2) which, will ultimately negatively impact your prediction accuracy.

With a lot less information given it is only logical your model can't predict classes as accurately as before.

Comment: Actually I have Dense() layer, ı just did not put here. I am wondering that when ı call classifier.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,input_shape = (64,64), activation ='relu')) function it predict well even if the input images are in shape 256*256. Even if my images are in shape 256*256 when ı apply con2d what happens. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**When to preprocess:**
This may be image of preprocessing. We only preprocess data when needed because when we pre-process our data we are losing some information. If we dont pre-process our data in certain cases than algorithms may take time to process big values(not preprocessed data).

1. We will pre-process data when we have less re-sources to train our model
2. We pre-process data because their are very large and very-small values in our data. than we normalize it standardize it and get our data in some range. like (0,1)
3. Their are many other reasons also to preprocess.

But we don't preprocess every data. You have first know the nature of data and than pre-process it.

**Your Solution:**
Now you are pre-processing your data by resizing your images. By converting your image from ((256,256)) to ((64,64)) now when you have large size image their are more pixel values in your image and every pixel give some information to us. Now when you resize your image you have less pixels so that why less information that your model can use to classify. But when you don't resize your data your machine takes time to process your images. Now find some middle way by experimentation that which size you select which will give enough information to your model and machine will do less effort to process that. try (180*180)
(164 *164) keep going down until your achieve your required accuracy according to the data.

Comment: Actually I did what you said. But the part that ı do not understand is, even if my images are in shape 256*256,  ı applied conv2D 64*64  as an input shape. By doing that what ı am missing ? Thank you for answer by the way.